# Find neural network models on Weka tool

Tags: neural-network, weka

I am having some difficulties finding these neural network models on Weka.

- Artificial Neural Network
- Feed Forward Neural Network
- Elman Network
- Back-propagation Neural Network

Could someone guide me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This [Information](http://bit.ly/1FFRZ8O) (contains some plug-in for weka). helped me with Artificial Neural Network, Back propagation and Feed-Forward Artificial Neural Network, for Elman Network I use this [another plug-in](http://jsalatas.ictpro.gr/weka/).

Comment: May I ask which option leads to the Feed forward neural network classifier in the weka toolkit and how may I install elman neural network into weka? Please kindly advise.

Comment: Hi, About elman neural network, im not sure if you can add this in weka, but you can try to add to the weka library and test with java. 
¿What you mean about the opcion lead to the Feed foward neural network? :)

Comment: Hi !BrennQuin, what I meat was, out of the neural network options in the weka toolset to train the model, which one of them points to the Feedforward neural network? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Farath Shba, as the author of the Elman algorithm for WEKA, I need to comment that it is designed in a bad way. In order to use it, you need to download WEKA's source code and copy the sources found in the Elman source code, over the WEKA's own source files overwriting them if asked.

I guess I need to redesign it :\